# замена значений во вложенном словаре python

Tags: python, словари, dict

есть исходные данные (словарь с вложенными словарями):

```py
dict = {
    "Shop1": {
        "apple": {"Can_buy": "allow", "amount": 5, "Can_sell": "restrict"},
        "orange": {"Can_buy": "restrict", "amount": 4, "Can_sell": "allow"},
    },
    "Shop2": {"Melon": {"Can_buy": "allow", "amount": 61, "Can_sell": "restrict"}},
}
```

Таким образом это словарь, ключи которого - магазины, а в значениях - словари. Уже в эти словарях ключ - название фрукта, а в значении этого ключа словарь с данными о возможности купить, количестве и возможности продать.

Задача в том, чтобы заменить значения '`allow`' и '`restrict`' на булевые `True` и `False` соответственно.

Наверное возможно это сделать тройным вложенным циклом и заменой значения по условию, но пока не знаю как именно

Буду очень рад вашей помощи

Comment: За что вопросу минус?)

Comment: @Павел вам не ответят)

Comment: @Dmitry ну, это на самом деле просто призыв поставить вопросу плюс, потому что он вполне полезен)

Comment: @Dmitry можете помочь пожалуйста решить данный вопрос другим методом? у меня есть другой словарь подобный, только там вместо 'allow' - 1, а вместо 'restrict' - 0. используя метод .replace могут замениться значения по ключу 'amount', что нежелательно

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если лениво разбираться с вложениями, то можно просто перевести данные в `json`, потом заменить строки и вернуть данные обратно в объект:

```py
import json
import pprint

data = {'Shop1': {'apple': {'Can_buy': 'allow', 'Can_sell': 'restrict', 'amount': 5},
                  'orange': {'Can_buy': 'restrict', 'Can_sell': 'allow', 'amount': 4}},
        'Shop2': {'Melon': {'Can_buy': 'allow', 'Can_sell': 'restrict', 'amount': 61}}}

new_data = json.loads(json.dumps(data).replace('"allow"', 'true').replace('"restrict"', 'false'))
pprint.pprint(new_data)
```

Вывод:

```
{'Shop1': {'apple': {'Can_buy': True, 'Can_sell': False, 'amount': 5},
           'orange': {'Can_buy': False, 'Can_sell': True, 'amount': 4}},
 'Shop2': {'Melon': {'Can_buy': True, 'Can_sell': False, 'amount': 61}}}
```

Comment: а если нужно заменить не строку 'allow', а булевое значение None на 0? Речь идет о значениях ключа 'amount'

Comment: Тогда ещё `.replace('null','0')`, но так уже не очень хорошо, вдруг где-то в переменных встретится подстрока `null` )

Comment: можете помочь пожалуйста решить данный вопрос другим методом? у меня есть другой словарь подобный, только там вместо 'allow' - 1, а вместо 'restrict' - 0. используя метод .replace могут замениться значения по ключу 'amount', что нежелательно

Comment: Ну тогда тут скорее всего нужно будет словарное сокращение использовать с несколькими вложенностями. Позже посмотрю